# Warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion

Tags: java

I am facing an issue with generics here. Can anyone please point me what I am missing over in the below statements?

1.

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion

List<Question> qList = (List) session.getAttribute("qList");
                                       ^
  required: List<Question>
  found:    List
```

2.

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion

List<ExamSchedule> eList = new <ExamSchedule>ArrayList();

required: List<ExamSchedule>
found:    ArrayList
```

I don't want to supress the warnings. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
List<Question> qList = (List) session.getAttribute("qList");
```

1. `session.getAttribute("qList");` will return instance of type `Object`. So you need to explicitly cast it.
2. `(List)` is just raw type, `List<String>` is generic type , so trying to cast raw type to generic type reference gives a warning.

Now, if you do this:

`List<Question> qList = (List<Question>) session.getAttribute("qList");`

The cast is a runtime check but there will be a type erasure at runtime, so there's actually no difference between a `List<String>` and `List<Foo>` etc.Hence you get that error.
So try `(List<?> list)` This type conversion verifies that the object is a `List` without caring about the types held within.

```
List<ExamSchedule> eList = new <ExamSchedule>ArrayList();
```

That is a syntax error.It should be `ArrayList<ExamSchedule>` , not `<ExamSchedule>ArrayList`.

Suggestions :

```
List<?> qList = (List<?>) session.getAttribute("qList");
List<ExamSchedule> eList = new ArrayList<ExamSchedule>();
```

Comment: You just get a different warning when you cast to a bounded type (`List<Question>`).

Comment: When i am casting after getting from the session,
`List<Question> qList = (List<Question>)session.getAttribute("qList");` 
This still shows the warning. Do i have to make any change in the statement when i am setting the list in the session ? 
My set statement is,
`session.setAttribute("qList", qList);`

Comment: @Noob Unchained Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 6):

Answer 1:

```
List<Question> qList = (List<Question>) session.getAttribute("qList");
```

Answer 2:

```
List<ExamSchedule> eList = new ArrayList<ExamSchedule>();
```

Grasp first the idea of [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

As for the first answer, if you're using `HttpSession`, there is no chance of calming the warnings without annotating your statement with `@SuppressWarnings` like so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Question> qList = (List<Question>) session.getAttribute("qList");
```

This is due to the Servlet API which returns an `Object` from `HttpSession.getAttribute()`. The compiler will warn you of type-safety (unchecked cast from `Object` to `List<Question>`) otherwise.

Comment: List<Question> qList = (List<Question>)session.getAttribute("qList"); This is still showing a warning.

Comment: So there is no way of removing the warning without supressing it ?

Comment: With Generics, some are feasible. For your case, no.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't have reified generics; the list doesn't carry its elements' type at runtime. So, an attempt to cast to a bounded type will give you a warning; you might think you know the type, but the compiler reminds you that might be wrong.

You *can* cast to an unbound collection, then check the type of each individual element.

```
List<?> tmp = (List<?>) session.getAttribute("qList");
if (tmp != null) {
  for (Object o : tmp) {
    Question q = (Question) o;
    /* Use q ... */
  }
}
```

If you need a `List<Question>` to pass to some API, you can copy the elements to a new, correctly declared list inside the loop. Obviously, this is a lot of clutter that you should factor into a utility method. But to make it flexible, you'd probably want to use dynamic type casts.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(Collection<?> c, Class<? extends T> type) {
  if (c == null)
    return null;
  List<T> list = new ArrayList(c.size());
  for (Object o : c)
    list.add(type.cast(o));
  return list;
}

List<Question> qList = asList((Collection<?>) session.getAttribute("qList"), Question.class);
```

[There are methods in `java.util.Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Class%29) that do *almost* what you need; unfortunately, they don't check the type of elements in the original wrapped collection. Also, since they wrap the underlying collection instead of creating a new, independent collection, they could still create type errors.

Luckily, the second question is easy:

```
List<ExamSchedule> eList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Did I miss sth.? How can this work, because the first parameter will be of type Object? ````List<Question> qList = asList(session.getAttribute("qList"), Question.class);````

Answer (score 0):

***This could help:-***

/Users/tadtab/src/main/java/com/tadtab/dao/ProductDAO.java:[73,66] [unchecked] unchecked conversion

```
[ERROR]   required: List<Product>
[ERROR]   found:    List
```

what happen was in the code I had

```
List<Product> productList = session.createQuery("from Product").list());
```

***In this case the right hand statement is not guaranteed that it will return 
List Products***

So I modified it by casting in the following way

```
 List<Product> productList = (List<Product>)session.createQuery("from Product").list());
```

and got another Got compilation error! on eclipse it is a warning. **stating unchecked cast**

I am using java 12 and still not sure why it is an error instead of warning

Solution:

**Finally I have to use Wilcard type**

```
List<?> productList = session.createQuery("from Product").list());
```

**and add explicity casting on 
    the elements of the List like this**

```
for(Object obj: productList){

    Product product = (Product)obj;
  // do something on product
}
```