# Unchecked cast warning vs Unchecked conversion warning, what's the difference between them?

Tags: java

In *Effective Java*, I find there are unchecked cast warning and unchecked conversion warning.

> When you program with generics, you will see many compiler warnings: unchecked cast warnings, unchecked method invocation warnings, unchecked parameterized vararg type warnings, and unchecked conversion warnings.

I think the unchecked cast warning will be thrown if the compiler cannot verify the type. So what's the difference between cast and conversion? And if there any documents about warnings in Java for reference?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Warning: unchecked unchecked conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475436/warning-unchecked-unchecked-conversion)

Comment: The first Unchecked Cast Warning gives the hint that the objects (parameters) are in raw form (Object). Example List = new ArrayList() gives the unchecked warning. Correct is, for eample, List<String> = new ArrayList<>(). The second warning gives the warning that the casting could delivers a wrong result. Example: long a = 100 and int b = a will cause the conversion warning.